# get all string separation combinations

Tags: python, string, bash, combinations

I have a string and I would like to get all of the possible combinations of groupings of them while keeping them in the same sequence. I thought of doing something like an n-gram approach and then concatenating the results.

So if I have the example string:

```
aa bb cc dd
```

I would like to get (in no particular order):

```
aa | bb cc dd
aa bb | cc dd
aa bb cc | dd
aa | bb cc | dd
aa | bb | cc dd
aa bb | cc | dd
aa | bb | cc | dd
```

I would prefer answers in bash or python.

Comment: This is certainly possible in bash, but not a particularly good idea. Are there no "real" languages available to you? Python? Perl?

Comment: @slim python would be possible, I could change the title

Comment: `aa | bb | cc dd` is repeated in expected output... do add what you tried to question as well...

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks for pointing out my typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with a recursive function:

The stopping case is an empty list of parameters - so the `while` loop doesn't get entered.

Otherwise we want:

- The parameters as supplied
- For each group that can be made using the first parameters (i.e. "aa","aa bb", "aa bb cc" etc.

  - that group, followed by a '|' followed by each of the possible groupings of the remaining parameters

So:

```
#!/bin/bash

combos()
{
    head=""
    echo $@
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
        head="$head $1"
        shift
        combos $@ | sed "s/^/$head |/" 
    done
}


combos aa bb cc dd
```

This does have some inconsistent spacing, trailing `|`s and repetition of one grouping. These can all be tidied up -- I've left that as an exercise.